# Svelte - changing a bound value in a click handler doesn't seem to update it

Tags: svelte

I have a simple demo app of [binding an input using Svelte](https://svelte.dev/docs#Element_bindings). This works, but during a click handler on that same element, I wish to reset the bound value.

[image]

Specifically I have bound an `input` to `draftMessage` and would like to set `draftMessage` back to an empty string after the message is submitted:

```
<script>

    let draftMessage = '';

    let handleSendMessageClick = function(event){
        var message = event.target.form.querySelector('input').value
        previousMessages.push(message)
        previousMessages = previousMessages

        // Clear draftMessage
        console.log(`Clearing draftMessage - why doesn't this work?`)
        draftMessage = ''
    }

    let previousMessages = [];
</script>

<h1>Type some things</h1>

<form>
  <input value={draftMessage}/>
  <button on:click|preventDefault={handleSendMessageClick}>Send</button>
</form>

{#each previousMessages as message}
  <p>{message}</p>
{/each}
```

There is a [live demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/895d2bf1e97d4e3f99d3bb8f77c49bd0?version=3.4.0)

**How can I change a bound value in a click handler?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You forgot `bind:`**, so the value of `draftMessage` never actually changes, so `draftMessage = ''` has no effect. You have a couple of options:

1. Do `<input bind:value={draftMessage}>` so that by the time you hit that line, `draftMessage` has a value other than the empty string. (You can now use that value instead of querying the DOM — `previousMessages = [...previousMessages, draftMessage]`). [Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/99ce462e1e8f44e5ae9f124591301a95?version=3.4.0)
2. Skip `draftMessage` entirely, and use the DOM throughout (`input.value = ''`). [Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/8a571210bb1445968356b8f6e8ad1fe8?version=3.4.0)